# ¿Cómo puedo parsear un paquete JSON que contiene objetos dentro de objetos?

Tags: android

Tengo este código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView resultado;
    private String json;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);

        json = "[{'date':{'timestamp':17238932}, 'time':{'timestamp':13232322}}]";
        try {
            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(json);
            JSONObject jsonDatos = jarray.getJSONObject(0);

//            resultado.setText();
            /* el timestamp de date */
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo sacar el valor de los timestamp parseando el JSON?

Answer (score 4):

Antes de responder la pregunta:

> ¿Cómo puedo parsear un paquete JSON que contiene objetos dentro de
>   objetos?

Hay algo importante a considerar,

- Si el .json inicia con { se considera como objeto Json.
- Si el .json inicia con [ es considerado como Arreglo Json.

Por lo tanto lo que deseas "parsear" es un JsonArray y lo puedes realizar de la siguiente forma:

```
        String date;
        String time;
        String json = "[{'date':{'timestamp':17238932}, 'time':{'timestamp':13232322}}]";

        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            //Obtenemos los JsonObject del JsonArray (en este ejemplo solo es uno).
            JSONObject objetoJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //Obtenemos los objetos.
            JSONObject jsonObjectDate = objetoJson.getJSONObject("date");
            JSONObject jsonObjectTime = objetoJson.getJSONObject("time");

            //A partir del objeto obtenemos los valores de date y time.
            date = jsonObjectDate.getString("timestamp");
            time = jsonObjectTime.getString("timestamp");

            Log.i("Resultado", "Array elemento " + i + ", valor date :" + date);
            Log.i("Resultado", "Array elemento " + i + ", valor time :" + time);

        }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

obteniendo como salida los valores `timestamp` dentro de los objetos `date` y `time` respectivamente:

```
valor date :17238932
valor time :13232322
```

#### Para obtener los valores de un Array de Strings por medio de `JSONArray`, se puede realizar de la siguiente forma:

```
String json = "[Uno, Dos, Tres, Cuatro, Cinco]";
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    //Obtiene el valor del elemento dentro del array. 
                    String elemento = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                    Log.i("AppJson", "elemento " + elemento);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("AppJson", "JSONException : " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

Obteniendo como salida:

```
elemento Uno
elemento Dos
elemento Tres
elemento Cuatro
elemento Cinco
```

Answer (score 1):

Las respuestas anteriores si bien son buenas quisiera proponerte otra variante utilizar una librería muy conocida llamada Gson es de google https://github.com/google/gson

Ahora lo que haras es crear una clase que tenga la estructura de tu json esto es muy util sobre todo cuando trabajas con respuestas de API rest que por lo general devuelven json.

La estructura de tu json es la siguiente:

```
public class JsonArrayTest{
        TimeStampJ date;
        TimeStampJ time;

        public TimeStampJ getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(TimeStampJ date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public TimeStampJ getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public void setTime(TimeStampJ time) {
            this.time = time;
        }

        public class TimeStampJ{
            long timestamp;

            public long getTimestamp() {
                return timestamp;
            }

            public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
                this.timestamp = timestamp;
            }
        }
    }
```

veras que coloque los set y los get para obtener y cargar si quisieras la información.

Ahora esta es la parte interesante que hace la libreria Gson para este caso harias algo asi:

```
String json_test = "[{'date':{'timestamp':17238932}, 'time':{'timestamp':13232322}}]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArrayTest[] arrJson = gson.fromJson(json_test,JsonArrayTest[].class);

for(JsonArrayTest objJson : arrJson){
  if(objJson!=null && objJson.getDate()!=null && objJson.getTime()!=null) {
    Log.v("timestamp_date", objJson.getDate().getTimestamp() + "");
    Log.v("timestamp_time", objJson.getTime().getTimestamp() + "");
  }
}
```

Hice una impresión en logcat para que veas que funciona y lo puedes hacer con cualquier tipo o estructura de json si no es un jsonArray cuando parseas con el fromJson no utilizarías "[]" pero en tu caso si los necesitas por la estructura de tu json. espero te sirva como otra opción para mi es muy útil y me ahorra mucho trabajo esta libreria.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que ver es como te llega el JSON e identificar los arrays, los objetos que tiene, la estructura que tiene. Un objeto puede tener un array como valor, así que lo primero es ir desmenuzando. En este ejemplo tienes un array de 1 solo elemento y como contenido tienes un objeto con 2 valores, así que a trocitos:

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(son);
    for(int i=0; i<= jarray.length(); i++) {
       //es un array, ponlo en un bucle

       //sacamoe el unico elemento que lleva cada elemento del array
       JSONObject d = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
       //d contiene la clave date y la clave time
       JSONObject fec = d.getJSONObject("date");
       //en fec sacamos el contenido de "date", que es otro objeto JSON
       String fecha = fec.getString("timestamp");
       Log.v("",fecha);

       //y ahora del mismo único elemento del primer elemento del array saco el otro valor
       JSONObject time = d.getJSONObject("time");
       String hora = time.getString("timestamp");
       Log.v("", hora);

      }
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```