# Librería loopj parseando JsonObjects y JsonArrays

Tags: android, json

Tengo un webservice que me retorna un Objeto con un Array y dentro de este, múltiples objetos en Json.

Ejemplo:

```
{"result":[{"Id":"20","temperatura":"34","humedad":"29","Insertado":"2016-07-01 12:19:42"},{"Id":"21","temperatura":"34","humedad":"29","Insertado":"2016-07-01 12:34:42"},{"Id":"22","temperatura":"35","humedad":"28","Insertado":"2016-07-01 12:49:43"},{"Id":"23","temperatura":"35","humedad":"19","Insertado":"2016-07-01 13:29:06"},{"Id":"24","temperatura":"31","humedad":"18","Insertado":"2016-07-01 13:44:07"},{"Id":"25","temperatura":"33","humedad":"16","Insertado":"2016-07-01 13:59:10"}]}
```

Aquí muestro mi código en Android:

```
private void CaptarParametros(String idObjeto) {

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put(UtilitiesGlobal.SENSOR_ID, idObjeto);

RequestHandle post = client.post(this, SENSORS_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
        JSONObject jsonobject = null;
        JSONObject dht11JSONbject = null;
        JSONArray dht11JSONarray = null;


        try {

            jsonobject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
            dht11JSONbject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("result");

            dht11JSONarray = new JSONArray(dht11JSONbject);
            JSONArray dht11 = dht11JSONarray.getJSONArray(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < dht11JSONarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = dht11.getJSONObject(i);
                String temperatura = item.getString("temperatura");
                String humedad = item.getString("temperatura");

            //Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + usuarioiJSONbject);
            Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + temperatura + humedad);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error, es como si parseara el primer elemento, pero los siguientes no:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Id":"19","temperatura":"35","humedad":"16","Insertado":"2016-07-01 12:19:24"}] at result of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Necesito extraer los parámetros por separado de la temperatura y por otro lado los parámetros de humedad pues luego los tengo que usar para crear una Chart con MPAndroidChart.

Comment: En el sitio en espanol puedes encontrar varias respuestas similares https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8874/cómo-puedo-parsear-un-paquete-json-que-contiene-objetos-dentro-de-objetos en tu pregunta sería obtener el JsonArray y posteriormente los objetos dentro del array.

Comment: Hola Elenasys. Probé varios ejemplos en el de Español, pero este que he puesto funcionó bien porque me lo transforma en una lista, justo lo que necesito para el MPAndroidChart. De todas maneras muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenemos un objeto con un array y a su vez sub-objetos. Transferimos el objeto y una vez trenemos el objeto ya solo tenemos que extraer el array y ponerlo en una lista.

```
 try {

                jsonobject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                //dht11JSONbject = jsonobject.getJSONObject("result");


                List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONArray cast = jsonobject.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject parametrosdht11 = cast.getJSONObject(i);
                    String temperatura = parametrosdht11.getString("temperatura");
                    String humedad = parametrosdht11.getString("humedad");
                    allNames.add(temperatura);
                    allNames.add(humedad);

                    //Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " + usuarioiJSONbject);
                    Log.i(UtilitiesGlobal.TAG, "onSuccess: loopj " +"temperatura: "+ temperatura +" humedad: " +humedad);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Me he guiado en la rerspuesta de:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136769/how-to-parse-jsonarray-in-android